# How to avoid missing property TypeScript error on types extending a function or array

Tags: typescript

When I define an interface which extends from a function or array, I have not found a way to properly create new instances without getting an error or using an `any` cast.

Is there a way to initialize such members without reverting to hacks?

Example with Function:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: any;
    (): void;
}

// how to create a Foo?
var foo: Foo;
foo = () => {}; // cannot convert type ... has non-optional property bar which is not present
foo.bar = "initialized!";
```

Example with Array:

```
interface Foo<T> extends Array<T> {
    bar: any;
}

// how to create a Foo?
var foo: Foo<any>;
foo = []; // cannot convert type ... has non-optional property bar which is not present
foo.bar = "initialized!";
```

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps you are looking for the optional operator

```
interface Foo<T> extends Array<T> {
  bar?: any;
}

var foo: Foo<any>;
foo = []; // No error
```

Placing the `?` after a property name but before the `:` makes the property optional. This means that the property does not have to exist but could.

**UPDATE**

If you **do** want the property to be required by the contract, then you *will* need to cast it. This is because TypeScript requires all objects that are instantiated with a literal (`[]`, or `{}`) to include all required members. The correct way to instantiate this *without* including a required property is to use a cast. Either `foo = <any>[];` or `foo = <Foo><any>[];`

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the optional property. However, this changes the "contract". I'm looking for a way to create and initialize obects implementing these interfaces without getting errors.

Comment: TypeScript rules require any object instantiated with a literal (eg. `[]`, or `{}`) to include *all* required members. The only way to instantiate an object with a literal without including these non-optional members is to use a cast like you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if I was missing some construct that would have allowed these initializations in the context of the object creation (something smimilar to the [object initializers in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx) if you're familiar with these).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question since I found a workaround in the meantime...

Using `Object.assign()` works well.

```js
interface Foo {
    bar: any;
    (): void;
}

var foo: Foo = Object.assign(
    function() {}, 
    { bar: "initialized!" });
```

Or

```js
interface Foo<T> extends Array<T> {
    bar: any;
}

var foo: Foo<any> = Object.assign(
    [],
    { bar: "initialized!" });
```

Comment: The meantime was over 5 years! :D